# How to change ExtentReports document title programmatically in Java?

Tags: java, html, extent, extentreports

I'm using [ExtentReports](http://extentreports.com/docs/versions/2/java/) in Java to generate multiple html report files. This step works fine, but when I open the reports in Chrome, all the tabs show "ExtentReports 2.0" as the document title. How do I update the document title programmatically?

Comment: Check my answer to [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49029527/how-to-save-a-file-extentreports-report-in-my-case-or-any-other-file-in-a-sp) which should answer your question.

Comment: My version of ExtentReports doesn't have the attachReporter method.

Comment: Which version would that be?  Mine is 3.0.6

Comment: Nevermind, I see you're using version 2.  Use the community version of [Version 3](http://extentreports.com/docs/versions/3/java/)